# How to promote non maven artifacts in Nexus?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, nexus, build-pipeline

I have a non maven project whose binaries get deployed to Nexus. 
I used gradle's maven plugin to create the artifacts and publish it to Nexus

Now, the trouble is how do I promote this artifacts to release in Nexus? I tried looking up the M2 release plugin for jenkins but it looks for the pom file in my source code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Gradle examples including usage with the Nexus staging suite in the [Nexus book examples](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-book-examples) and [eval guide](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/eval.html).